# BLE HID over GATT callback is not called

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, hid

I work to a Android app that connect to a BLE device that implement HID over GATT communication protocol. What I have to do is to get some notification from device when a button is pressed, turn on some leds or read some parameters. The problem is callbacks are not called and I can not read or write data to device and also onCharacteristicChanged is never called.

Here is my callback:

```
    private final BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            gatt.discoverServices();
            Log.d(TAG, "CONNECTED");
        } else {

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        //super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
        Log.d("OnServDiscovered", "REACHEd");
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            BluetoothGattService service = gatt.getService(HID_UUID);
            if (service != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Service not null");
                final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = service.getCharacteristic(HID_REPORT_UUID);
                if (characteristic != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Characteristic not null");
                    setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
                    characteristic.setValue(new byte[]{(byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0x1F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00});
                    Log.d(TAG, "Write status:" + gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
        Log.d("onCharacteristicChanged", characteristic.getStringValue(0));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);

        Log.d(TAG, "OnCharacteristicWrite reached");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDescriptorWrite(final BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
        super.onDescriptorWrite(gatt, descriptor, status);
        Log.d("ON DESC WRITE", "REACHED. CODE:" + String.valueOf(status));

    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);
        Log.d("ONCHARREAD", "REACHED!!!!");
    }
};
```

Status of Read/Write from/to characteristic or descriptors is true but callbacks never fires. Service, Characteristic, Descriptor are not null but I have an error in Logcat.

```
09-24 09:55:20.800 22527-22540/com.example.pcostache.tstyt 
D/MainActivity: CONNECTED
09-24 09:55:20.812 22527-22540/com.example.pcostache.tstyt 
D/BluetoothGatt: onSearchComplete() = Device=00:08:D3:F2:00:XX Status=0
09-24 09:55:20.812 22527-22540/com.example.pcostache.tstyt 
E/BluetoothGatt: Broken GATT database: can't find included service.
09-24 09:55:20.813 22527-22540/com.example.pcostache.tstyt 
D/OnServDiscovered: REACHEd
09-24 09:55:20.813 22527-22540/com.example.pcostache.tstyt D/SERV: NOT 
NULL
09-24 09:55:20.813 22527-22540/com.example.pcostache.tstyt 
D/Characteristic: NOT NULL
09-24 09:55:20.817 22527-22540/com.example.pcostache.tstyt D/STAT: 
SUCCES
```

Broken GATT database come from this piece of code from Android:

```
                    // Fix references to included services, as they doesn't point to right objects.
                for (BluetoothGattService fixedService : mServices) {
                    ArrayList<BluetoothGattService> includedServices =
                            new ArrayList(fixedService.getIncludedServices());
                    fixedService.getIncludedServices().clear();

                    for (BluetoothGattService brokenRef : includedServices) {
                        BluetoothGattService includedService = getService(mDevice,
                                brokenRef.getUuid(), brokenRef.getInstanceId());
                        if (includedService != null) {
                            fixedService.addIncludedService(includedService);
                        } else {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Broken GATT database: can't find included service.");
                        }
                    }
                }
```

After a long period of research I really can not understand what is happening here and any help or suggestion will be wonderful. Thank you!

Comment: The connection success callback is getting, right? Did you initiate findservice() from connection success callback?

Comment: Yes, I think you mean gatt.discoverServices(); and yes I call it.

Comment: Ok than probably you got a callback in onServicesDiscovered() right? Are you able to filter the service from there?

Comment: Yes. I can filter the service also I can read battery and other information that are under another UUID but when I go to HID UUID I can select a characteristic from that, a descriptor from that characteristic, I can write to descriptor or characteristic with a return state true but callbacks never calls. I also triet with nRF Connect app and when I press to read or write it remain blocket at gatt.readCharacteristic()/gatt.writeCharacteristic();

Comment: Maybe the firmware issue. I have faced a similar issue with my BLE. To read/write certain characteristics my BLE required a delay. I have found this workaround after a long research.

Comment: I know that delay help when you want to read multiple char/descr but a best practice is to read first char on onServiceDiscovered and next char on callbacks.

Comment: @C.Paul did you find the sloution i'm also facing same issue.